# Youtube videos all appear transparent in Chrome (I can see through to my desktop -- see pic!)

Tags: mac, google-chrome, browser, flash

`MBP 6,2 :: Google Chrome 13.0.782.32 beta :: Adobe Flash Player 10,3,181,26`

UPDATE: only Youtube is affected. Vimeo, other flash, etc. all works great.

Hello.
I recently had to hard reboot my MBP. After that, I could not watch Youtube videos <del>or (I believe) other flash enabled content.</del>

The videos appear transparent, as if there were a "hole" in my browser (Chrome) such that I could see through the hole and see my desktop.

I've attached a picture (just picked a random video)

[image]
Thanks.

Comment: Interesting cool bug.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I figured it out -- I was running a beta version of chrome (v13.x.x...). I uninstalled the beta version and installed v12 -- everything is working again.